# What verb is most proper to act on "scholarship?" Win, be awarded, recieve?

Tags: verbs

Word count is killing me on one of my applications. My go-to is to used "I was awarded a scholarship." over "I won a scholarship." Is there any benefit to the former?

Full sentence:

After my $100 became $190 via a truly diverse stock portfolio (one Apple share), finance seemed the place to be to my eighteen-year-old self. So, being awarded the ____ Scholarship was seemingly a godsend.

versus

After my $100 became $190 via a truly diverse stock portfolio (one Apple share), finance seemed the place to be to my eighteen-year-old self. Winning the ____ Scholarship was then seemingly a godsend.

Cheers!

Comment: If you are looking at word count, I would rewrite "to my eighteen-year-old self" as "at age 18."

Comment: Hmmmm I dont like how that sounds... is this proper? "After my $100 became $190 via a truly diverse stock portfolio (one Apple share), finance seemed the place to be as an eighteen-year-old. Winning the ____ Scholarship was then seemingly a godsend." Is that hyphenation proper when it is a noun and not describing "self" as before?

Comment: I also suggested that change because "to my eighteen-year-old self" sounds self-indulgent, like you love your achievement.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you explain further? The sentence should come off as "I entered college under a silly assumption that I would like financial studies because I thought the stock market was magic after being a penniless eighteen year old (hyphenation since its a noun? can anyone answer this/above comment?) and seeing my investment nearly double."

Comment: I assumed this is a resume being written, because you mention "application." If so I would use a different style.

Comment: I apologize — this is for a personal statement. (The application also has a statement of purpose where I am naturally more formal and talk about research. For reference here is an example of what the prompts for these personal statements look like: "How have your background and life experiences, including cultural, geographical, financial, educational, citizenship status or other opportunities or challenges, motivated your decision to pursue a graduate degree at the University of ________?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you came to acquire it:

- you *won* it in a competition;
- it was *granted* upon your application; or perhaps
- it was *awarded* to you for good results.

Or you could simply say that it was a relief to *get* the scholarship.

Comment: huh! that makes win a totally valid choice then! Since the scholarship I'm talking about is one I APPLIED for and competed against other for, versus a scholarship one gets in college for good grades in high school or something! Thank you! :)